# ¿Porque al pasar con sockets texto me añade al final cosas así `Fjw`"f?

Tags: c, socket, binario

Estoy intentando pasar con socks archivos binarios desde un ordenador a otro pasándolos línea por linea.
Mi programa hace que se escriba en una consola antes de enviar y después en la otra consola cuando llega y al final de las líneas siempre me encuentro cosas como esta `Fjw"f` o esta `Fjw"i` siempre con `fjw` (viene con comillas antes y después del fjw pero aquí no las puedo poner porque se ve feo) y después algo más.Si alguien pudiese explicarme porque pasa eso se lo agradecería mucho.

Probando me he dado cuenta de que las letras que añade al final de la línea son la misma mientras no reinicio el servidor por lo que imagino que el problema está ahí. Este es el código de la función que recibe los datos del archivo.

```
void archivo(SOCKET s,char nombre[])
{
    FILE *f;
    char buf[2024];

    f=fopen(nombre,"wb");

    recv(s,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
    printf("\n%s\n",buf);
    fwrite(buf,1,strlen(buf),f);

    while((buf[0]!='4')&&(buf[0]!='6')&&(buf[0]!='8')&&(buf[0]!='1')&&(buf[0]!='9')&&(buf[0]!='7'))
    {
       system("pause");
       fwrite(buf,1,strlen(buf),f);
       recv(s,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
       printf("linea:%s",buf);
    }
    printf("acabado\n");
    fclose(f);
}
```

Esta es la función que envia los datos en el cliente:

```
void copiar_archivo(SOCKET s,char direccion[])
{
    FILE *f;
    char nom[30];
    char mensaje[40]="22";
    char buff[2024];


    nombre(direccion,nom);
    f=fopen(direccion,"rb");
    strcat(mensaje,nom);

    printf("comienzo\n");
    send(s,mensaje,sizeof(mensaje),0);
    strcpy(mensaje,"");

    while( 0 == feof(f) )
    {
        fread(buff,1,sizeof(buff),f);
        send(s,buff,sizeof(buff),0);
        printf("%s",buff);
    }

    send(s,"468197",sizeof("468197"),0);
}
```

Este es el resultado del archivo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A ver, aquí hay varias incógnitas ¿qué hace `nombre`? ¿Qué valor tiene `direccion`? ¿Dónde estás viendo el problema exactamente? ¿En  el fichero? ¿En la consola donde imprimes `linea:`? ¿en otro sitio?

Comment: @eferion dirección es la ruta del archivo en el oredenador del que lo va a mandar, nombre coge la direccion y deja en nom solo el nombre del archivo sin toda la ruta y el problema lo veo tanto en el archivo como en la consola del ordenador que reciven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### El problema

La línea que tienes para recibir datos es:

```
recv(s,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
```

Esa línea dice que *como máximo* se lean 2024 bytes (que es el tamaño del array `buf`), pero en la práctica puedes leer menos, (porque el cliente te ha enviado menos, o por diferentes problemas en los buffers de red intermedios). Pongamos que el cliente envía "Hola". Tal como tienes el envío, que no incluye el terminador de cadena, el socket recibirá solo 4 bytes.

Por tanto en el array `buf` tendrás al inicio los 4 bytes recibidos (que son el texto "Hola") pero a continuación otros 2020 bytes más que no sabes lo que tienen, y que pueden contener todo tipo de "basura".

Cuando intentas imprimir `buf` con un `printf("%s\n", buf)`, lo que esta función espera es una serie de letras al final de las cuales *debe haber* un **terminador de cadena** (un byte con valor 0). `printf()` irá imprimiendo letras hasta encontrar ese terminador. Por tanto mostrará "Hola", pero también el resto de "basura" que haya detrás, y se detendrá sólo cuando (casualmente) encuentre un byte de valor 0. Esto podría no ocurrir, y llevar a tu programa a seguir leyendo de memoria e imprimiendo basura hasta alcanzar una dirección de memoria protegida que causaría finalmente un *segfault* y la terminación del programa.

En tu caso has tenido suerte (bueno, no estoy seguro :-)) y encontró un 0 que le hizo parar antes del *segfault*. Y te saca siempre la misma secuencia de "letras basura" porque esa parte de `buf` nunca se sobreescribe (porque nunca recibes tantos bytes en un solo `recv`). Y por eso en otra ejecución de tu server la "basura" que sale es otra, pero siempre la misma en todas las líneas.

### Solución

Una solución es añadir a `buf` ese terminador para evitar que `printf()` siga imprimiendo lo que no debe.

La función `recv()` te retorna un entero que te indica cuántos bytes recibió en realidad. Puedes usar ese valor para añadir un 0 en la posición apropiada dentro `buf`. Es decir:

```
int recibidos;
recibidos = recv(s,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
buf[recibidos] = 0;
```

Así, en el ejemplo anterior, `recibidos` valdría 4, y se estaría metiendo un 0 en `buf[4]`, lo que es correcto porque el mensaje ("Hola") está en los índices 0, 1, 2, y 3.

Otra opción es forzar a que el cliente que te está enviando el texto incluya entre los bytes enviados el terminador en cuestión. Para eso el cliente debe enviar **un byte más** que el valor de `strlen()`, pues es ese byte extra el que contiene el terminador.

De todas formas me parece más robusta la solución de añadir el terminador en quien recibe, pues funcionará bien tanto si el cliente te lo está enviando como si no.

Ah! Y asegúrate de declarar el buffer que recibe de tamaño 2025, por si el cliente enviara exactamente 2024 bytes, para asegurarte de que aún en ese caso tienes sitio para el terminador que estamos añadiendo.

Comment: Muchisímas gracias ahora lo pruebo.

Comment: oye sabrías porque no me funciona con imagenes pero con archivos de texto si si he puesto un archivo binario

Comment: Un binario que no sea texto podría contener bytes con valor cero. Tal como lo tienes enfocado esos ceros no se estarían tomando como parte del mensaje, sino como terminadores, y por tanto no se estarían guardando. Para este caso no deberías añadir el 0 terminador, ni usar strlen() en el fwrite(), sino`recibidos`. Naturalmente tampoco puedes usar printf() para mostrar por pantalla lo recibido.

Comment: Gracias luego lo intento y te digo

Answer (score 1):

Cambia esto

```
   fwrite(buf,1,strlen(buf),f);
```

Por esto

```
   fwrite(buf,1,strlen(buf) + 1,f);
```

Al enviar los datos no estás incluyendo el finalizador de string `\0`.

Al leer, recuperas la cadena del socket pero se dan dos circunstancias:

- La cadena no cuenta con finalizador
- El buffer no tiene sus bytes inicializados a `\0`

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora miro si resuelve el problema del todo

Comment: Lo cabao de probar XD y me sigue pasando exactamente lo mismo 

Comment: @julianix La llamada que tienes que tocar es la que envía datos por el socket, el código que estás poniendo aquí es únicamente el que recibe datos del socket. Tu problema no se ha solucionado porque no has editado la línea adecuada

Comment: he intentado cambiar algunas cosas pero no ha funcionado la función que envia la acabo de poner en la pregunta

Comment: perdon ya lo he quitado